# Linker Error 1120 when trying to build c++ extension for python using setuptools/distutils

Tags: python, c++, linker, swig, distutils

I am in the process of creating a dynamic library in C++ (with .pyd extension) that bundles a static C++ library along with it. The intention is to import the library in Python and use it within the current test framework I have.

I followed the documentation and used swig to generate a .cxx file. I then wrote a distutils setup.py file as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension    
xy = Extension('_xy',
                                   sources='xy_wrap.cxx','main.cpp',],
                                   include_dirs = [r'<project>\Include',r'<project>\Source'],
                                    library_dirs = [r'<libdir>\Release',r'C:\Python27\libs'],
                                    libraries = ['xy ','python27'],
                                    )

setup (name = 'xy',
           version = '0.1',
           author = "Rivas",
           description = """The Library Interface which can be used for automation""",
           ext_modules = [xy_module],
           py_modules = ["xy"],
           )
```

I am also using the VS 9.0 for compiling the python sources. The compilation seems to go through but it is flagging a linker error and all seem to be linked to the linker not finding the right library files (the python as well as my own). A sample of the errors I am putting below.

```
    Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_xy.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_xy.exp
        PyCSPSDKLite_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyString_FromString referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl SWIG_Python_str_FromChar(char const *)" (?SWIG_Python_str_FromChar@@YAPAU_object@@PBD@Z)
        PyCSPSDKLite_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_RuntimeError referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl SWIG_Python_ErrorType(int)" (?SWIG_Python_ErrorType@@YAPAU_object@@H@Z)
        PyCSPSDKLite_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_AttributeError referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl SWIG_Python_ErrorType(int)" (?SWIG_Python_ErrorType@@YAPAU_object@@H@Z)
...    
: fatal error LNK1120: 59 unresolved externals
```

I have included the library directories as well as related binaries but that still doesn't seem to be resolving the issue.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
[Note: I have renamed the project to xy]

Comment: Have you ensured that Python and your static library are both 32-bit or 64-bit? Do you run your `setup.py` file from a "Visual Studio Console"?

Comment: I ensured that python and static library are both 64 bit. But I havent run it from a VS Console. I figured that distutils did not need VS Console.

Comment: Yes and no. The compiler environment must be set up correctly. A simple installation of WinPython or Anaconda does not ensure this. Try run `python setup.py` from a VS Console